# Sharedpreferences apply themes with button in custom activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, themes, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener

( first sorry for bad english ) 
I would like to know how i can change a value of preference with a button in an Custom Activity. I've use a PreferenceActivity to store my themes. So this Sample works great when i want to change theme by PreferenceScreen but I want to do the same thing in a custom activity.See Screens!

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByGwmav6zTzlWUtoXzdvbnhucjA&usp=sharing

So I have my PreferenceScreen

***MyPreferencesActivity.java***

```
package com.itec.project.basic;

import com.itec.project.basic.MainActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
    public static int themeId;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(MyPreferenceActivity.themeId);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add the preference xml to display
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                // implementation goes here
                changeTheme();
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    // change theme is what I use to check if a theme was selected
    private void changeTheme() {
        // Initialize preferences
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // read preference
        String pref_Theme = preferences.getString("pref_Theme", "");

        if (pref_Theme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Yellow")) {
            MainActivity.scheduledRestart = true;
            themeId = R.style.Yellow;
        } else if (pref_Theme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Red")) {
            MainActivity.scheduledRestart = true;
            themeId = R.style.Red;
        } else if (pref_Theme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Teal")) {
            MainActivity.scheduledRestart = true;
            themeId = R.style.Teal;
        } else if (pref_Theme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Green")) {
            MainActivity.scheduledRestart = true;
            themeId = R.style.Green;
        } else if (pref_Theme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Pink")) {
            MainActivity.scheduledRestart = true;
            themeId = R.style.Pink;
        } else if (pref_Theme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Grey")) {
            MainActivity.scheduledRestart = true;
            themeId = R.style.Grey;
        } else if (pref_Theme.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Android Default")) {
            MainActivity.scheduledRestart = true;
            themeId = R.style.Indigo;
        }
    }
}
```

I've my preferences files

***preferences.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<ListPreference
    android:key="pref_Theme"
    android:title="Theme"
    android:dialogTitle="Theme"
    android:entries="@array/pref_Theme_Entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_Theme_Values"
    android:defaultValue="Indigo"
    android:summary="Change the Theme"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And my arrays file

***arrays.xml***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <string-array name="pref_Theme_Entries">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    <item>Teal</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Pink</item>
    <item>Grey</item>
    <item>Android Default</item>
    <item>Reset</item>
 </string-array>
 <string-array name="pref_Theme_Values">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
    <item>Teal</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Pink</item>
    <item>Grey</item>
    <item>Android Default</item>
    <item>Reset</item>
 </string-array>
 </resources>
```

and I would like to change theme as in the Preference screen in a custom activity with buttons but this activity is a Fragment ( I uses a slinding menu )
I try this but sure it's not the good way !
***ThemesFragment.java***

```
package com.itec.project.basic;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class ThemeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Boolean scheduledRestart = false;
    public static int themeId;
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.themes, container, false);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        final String pref_Theme = preferences.getString("pref_Theme", "");

        final Button go = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_go);
        final Button indigo = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_indigo);
        final Button purple = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_purple);
        final Button pink = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_pink);
        final Button red = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_red);
        final Button orange = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_orange);
        final Button yellow = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_yellow);
        final Button green = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_green);
        final Button teal = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_teal);
        final Button blue = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_blue);

        View.OnClickListener Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*
                 * if button yellow is clicked I want to apply theme as in
                 * PreferencesScreen with case ! but this way doesn't works
                 */
                if (v.equals(yellow)) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(pref_Theme, "Yellow");
                    editor.apply();

                    scheduledRestart = true;
                    themeId = R.style.Yellow;

                }
            }
            /* Here same for other buttons */

        };
        go.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        indigo.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        purple.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        pink.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        red.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        orange.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        yellow.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        green.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        teal.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        blue.setOnClickListener(Listener);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Slide Navigation Menu for the list of themes to be chosen . Save the value of the theme selected in a Share Preferrence and then register onshareprefernceschangelistener  in your activity. and implement onsharedpreferncechangelistener. then update your UI in the onsharedpreferencechangelistener. Or if You want to just detect the click from your preference activity then don,t implement Side navigation menu and just implement sharedpreferencechange listener

Comment: Oh sorry I would like to say that i've a side menu  and i want to change theme trought one of these fragment ^^ so i don't need an other side nav sorry

Comment: you are not needed to change anything in the side menu just implement the sharedpreferencelistener in the activity \

Comment: "Cannot resolve method getSaredPreferences and getApplicationContext " for context in fragment have i to change with Context context =getActivity()?

Comment: getApplication().getSharedPreference() or context.getSharedPreference

Comment: context.getSharedPreferences()* and no error but i don't know the end of your edit how can i update UI by click event ?

Comment: create a function for updating UI and just call that function in onsharedprefercechange event

Comment: Yeah like in my PreferenceActivity with "changeTheme()" I know that but i don't know how to write this function because i use a fragment that inflate layout by " View v=..." and i need a return statment (return v) so this return is before the if{v.equals("btn") and i can't do that after return v :/